# Select difference between row dates in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to calculate the difference in unique date fields between different rows in the same table.

For instance, given the following data:

```
   id | date
   ---+------------
    1 | 2011-01-01
    2 | 2011-01-02
    3 | 2011-01-15
    4 | 2011-01-20
    5 | 2011-01-10
    6 | 2011-01-30
    7 | 2011-01-03
```

I would like to generate a query that produces the following:

```
id | date       | days_since_last
---+------------+-----------------
 1 | 2011-01-01 | 
 2 | 2011-01-02 |  1
 7 | 2011-01-03 |  1
 5 | 2011-01-10 |  7
 3 | 2011-01-15 |  5
 4 | 2011-01-20 |  5
 6 | 2011-01-30 | 10
```

Any suggestions for what date functions I would use in MySQL, or is there a subselect that would do this?

(Of course, I don't mind putting `WHERE date > '2011-01-01'` to ignore the first row.)

Comment: This is where it'd be nice that MySQL support analytics, LEAD & LAG to be specific...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A correlated subquery could be of help:

```
SELECT
  id,
  date,
  DATEDIFF(
    (SELECT MAX(date) FROM atable WHERE date < t.date),
    date
  ) AS days_since_last
FROM atable AS t
```

Comment: This will work, which is good, but it will perform like crap due to the nested subquery (you'll do "n" table scans). The best way would be to use a variable to store the previous row's date value after ordering by date - and make just one pass. I can't be bothered right now, but if you want to have a go... :)

Comment: This is what I thought I was looking for, but as Bohemian said, the performance hurts.  It took 28 minutes to complete (with about 26,000 rows).  I'm selecting this as the best answer to my question, but for sanity sake it may be best to use temporary tables and follow Krtek's answer.

Comment: @Mike S.: I'm surprised by two things. First, I'm surprised that it performed so poorly on such a tiny table. Please don't get me wrong, I quite realise that this solution may not be the fastest one, it may even be rather below average, but 28 min on 26,000 rows... Could it be that the table lacks an index on `date`? Anyway, one other things that has surprised me is that you've chosen this answer in the first place. :) I mean I appreciate it, thanks, but believe me, based on your own words I myself now find Krtek's answer closer to the 'correct' solution, whatever it may eventually turn out.

Comment: Ahhh Krtek's answer is no good: matching on "previous id" is useless - see sample data from question for why (consecutive id's don't have consecutive dates)

Comment: @Bohemian: My understanding is the OP was talking about using a temporary table before directly applying Krtek's answer. That is, the data are ordered by `date` and are inserted into a temporary table which has its own autoincrement column. Then Krtek's solution is applied to the temp table. But maybe I'm wrong and Mike meant something else.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work :

```
 SELECT mytable.id, mytable.date, DATEDIFF(mytable.date, t2.date)
 FROM mytable
 LEFT JOIN mytable AS t2 ON t2.id = table.id - 1
```

However, this imply that your `id` are continuous in your table, otherwise this won't work at all. And maybe MySQL will complain for the first row since `t2.date` will be `null` but I don't have the time to check now.

Comment: You beat me to the answer, so I'll just add my piece and suggest he take a look at the documentation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff

Comment: @Krtek, thanks for the quick response.  I'll have to update my question to better reflect the situation, as the ids are not in chronological order.

Comment: @Tchami - thanks for your vote of confidence. ;) rest assured, I know where the documentation is and consult it frequently.

Comment: I never said you didn't ;) But it might be of help to someone else stumbling upon this question.

Comment: This completely won't work. Check the OP's data - ids and dates are not continuous.

Comment: @Bohemian Like the OP said in one of the comments to this answer, the question was updated to reflect this fact... When I wrote the answer I didn't know this !

Comment: Regardless, if the OP's dates would have been all contiguous, then there'd be no need for the query, because days_since would always = 1.